# How to color bars drawn in Pane?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

To lower the mess, I moved one of my overlayed indicators into a Pane but needed to plot bars there, too, so see the chart context. Plus, I re-color bars. ***The problem is***, `barcolor()` function re-colors bars on the main chart area, not on the Pane.

How to tell `barcolor()` to do the re-coloring for the candles/bars drawn on the Pane itself (where my indicator draws to), instead of the main chart area??

Comment: I assume zou use the `plotcandle()` function to draw the candles. Why not use its `color` argument?

Comment:  Pfft, it could have been obvious… ‍♂️  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plotcandle()` has three arguments for the color. You can use those to color your candles.

```
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, title, color, wickcolor, editable, show_last, bordercolor, display) → void
```

> **color (series color)** Color of the candles. You can use constants like
> 'color=color.red' or 'color=#ff001a' as well as complex expressions
> like 'color = close >= open ? color.green : color.red'. Optional
> argument.
>
> **wickcolor (series color)** The color of the wick of candles. An optional
> argument. editable (const bool) If true then plotcandle style will be
> editable in Format dialog. Default is true.
>
> **bordercolor (series color)** The border color of candles. An optional
> argument.